# Wakanda v10 Git: If GUI push fails, Git thinks there's nothing to push upon retry

Tags: git, wakanda

When I use Wakanda Enterprise v10's Git button (Git -> Push to Git Server), and my repository (on a NAS) is disconnected, it will fail to push, but all my modified files will show the green light, as though they have been committed (this is on my dev machine).

I suspect they have been committed to my dev machine's local repository but not committed to the server repository. When I reconnect my NAS and try to push again, there's nothing to push. On my webserver, when I try to pull via GUI, there is nothing to pull.

How do I get these files into the repository where they can be pulled by my webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer pretty quickly. It was risky to do if I was wrong as some of the code would have been synced and some of it not. All I did was modified any file (removed a character from a comment line), and did a GUI push again. When I executed a GUI pull on the webserver, it pulled all new changes; not just the one newly-changed file.